# Query Firebase object where object contains userID

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a Firebase database containing a product list and each product has a sublist of cart elements. I would like to only receive the product elements containing a cart element with the right userID.

I am using FirebaseUI listadapter. I get all the elements of the product list but i would like to only show the products containing the userID.

Can i delete Views from the ListAdapter? Or can sort by some query?

All ideas to solve the problem are welcome!

**EDIT**

Here is part of the Product Class.

```
public class Product implements Serializable{

    private boolean active;

    private ArrayList<Cart> carts;

    private String description;

    private String details;

    private String ean;

    private String id;

    private String image;

    private String name;

    private Float price;

    private ArrayList<ProductPack> productpacks;

    private int stock;

    private int stockavailable;

    private Float tax;

    private String users; 
}
```

Part of the data stored in firebase:

```
products
     -KG8O_5iHKWGCBytLtn0
         active: true
         carts
             0
                 amount: 11
                 userID: "google:116879660852602200588"
             1
                 amount: 12
                 userID: "google:116879660852602200589"
         description: ""
         details:  ""
         ean: ""
         id: "-KG8O_5iHKWGCBytLtn0"
         image: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABqsAAAPACAIAAAAt5NQJAAA..."
         name: "test"
         price: 1
         stock: 0
         stockavailable: 0
         tax: 1
         users: ""
     -KG9-r5ATr1BokkVzuYt
         active: true
         carts
             0
                 amount: 11
                 userID: "google:116879660852602200588"
             1
                 amount: 12
                 userID: "google:116879660852602200589"
         description: ""
         details: ""
         ean: ""
         id: "-KG9-r5ATr1BokkVzuYt"
         image: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABqsAAAPACAIAAAAt5NQJAAA..."
         name: "test"
         price: 1
         stock: 0
         stockavailable: 0
         tax: 0.25
         users: ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the Firebase server to filter the data is returns by using a query:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com");
Firebase products = ref.child("products");
Query userProducts = products.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(authData.uid);

FirebaseListAdapter<Product> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Product>(
    this,
    Product.class,
    R.layout.product_layout,
    userProducts
) { ...
```

This is documented in the [Firebase documentation on queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries), which I highly recommend reading. A few hours spent in the [Firebase guide for Android developers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide), will save you much time down the line.

### A data structure more optimized for this use case

While this will work, you seem to have applied a SQL-like structure to a NoSQL database. To return the `userProducts`, the Firebase server will have to consider all products. As the list of products*users grows, this will start taking more and more time.

A more read-optimized structure takes into account that you typically want to access the products for a user, so it stores the products per user.

```
UserProducts
  uid1
    product1: { ... }
    product3: { ... }
    product5: { ... }
  uid2
    product2: { ... }
    product4: { ... }
    product6: { ... }
```

Now you can access the products for the user:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com");
Firebase products = ref.child("UserProducts");
Firebase userProducts = products.child(authData.uid);

FirebaseListAdapter<Product> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Product>(
    this,
    Product.class,
    R.layout.product_layout,
    userProducts
) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I considered using the second option but then i would have to update the product changes in multiple places wich doesnt feel that good.

Comment: That's your SQL gland speaking. Once your NoSQL gland becomes dominant, the feeling will get better. :-)